# Can a South African apply for a work Z visa in Hong Kong?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, china, hong-kong, south-african-citizens

I am a South African going to work in Malaysia for a month. Afterwards I am going to work in Forsan, China. 
I could not complete the Visa process in South Africa, due to slow service. I would like to apply for my Z visa in Hong Kong as it will be a shorter, cheaper flight.
Would this be possible? Any other advice appreciated!!

Comment: You must look at the requirements set out by the Malaysian representative authority and be more specific about the permit allowing you to work in Hong Kong for the month. Most times the consulates limit who is eligible to use their services to those legally residing in the country under their Consular jurisdiction.